# Reader monad inside RxJs mergeMap

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, rxjs, fp-ts, reader-monad

I am using `rxjs` and want to use `Reader` monad from `fp-ts` package as a Dependency Injection solution.

Here is my code:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/function';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as R from 'fp-ts-rxjs/ReaderObservable';

type Dependency = { dep1: string }

const fn1 = (input: string): R.ReaderObservable<Dependency, string> => (dep: Dependency) =>
  of(`${input} | ${dep.dep1}`);

const fn2 = () => pipe(
  of('initial').pipe(
    mergeMap(x => pipe(
      fn1(`| inside merge map ${x}`),
    )),
  ),
);

fn2()({dep1: "something"}).subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
);
```

`fn1` function has a dependency that is injected using `Reader` monad

The problem is when I use this function inside a `mergeMap` the return value is a `ReaderObservable` and not an `Observable` and causes errors.

How can I use `ReaderObservable` inside a `mergeMap`?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `mergeMap`'s callback must return either an `Observable` or an `ObservableInput`:

```
type ObservableInput<T> = SubscribableOrPromise<T> | ArrayLike<T> | Iterable<T>;
```

But a `ReaderObservable` is a [function](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts-rxjs/blob/3d43883b37c2262048b704ce597bf4275dfe34d9/src/ReaderObservable.ts#L34) that returns an `Observable`.

Anything that expects `Observable | ObservableInput` won't be able to use it without actually invoking it with the dependency.

---

So how can you use it? Well, at what point is your dependency actually going to be injected? Your code example doesn't show the actual point of injection. At a minimum, the dependency must be in scope within the `mergeMap` callback so you can convert the `ReaderObservable` to an actual `Observable`.

Comment: `fn2` doesn't know about `fn1` dependency. How should I invoke it with the dependency inside mergeMap?
The dependency will inject when I want to subscribe at the last line.
`fn2().subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
);`

Comment: I don't see that demonstrated in the code. In what scope does the dependency exist?

Comment: I need something like this at top level where I want to send the actual dependencies:
`fn2()({dep1: "something"}).subscribe(
  data => console.log(data),
);`

Comment: OK, please update the question with the code as you think it should work. Right now you have `fn2().subscribe(...)`, which is different from your most recent comment. The code in your question should be a [mre].

Comment: Do you have any solution?